# Trying to connect to Oracle DB through Electron in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm, electron

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database through the Electron app I'm building. What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [node-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb).  Electron has some [ABI compatibility issues](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5851#issuecomment-226093160) so review what other node-oracledb users are [doing](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/search?q=electron&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) before you start.